# Mercure with symfony not working with vue

Tags: vue.js, symfony, mercure

I got a problem with configure mercure under symfony with vue. I'm using mercure hub which is attached in symfony cli. in .env file I changed mercure urls to using http because it caused me error with certificate(which was included by symfony).

**.env**

```
MERCURE_URL=http://localhost:8000/.well-known/mercure
MERCURE_PUBLIC_URL=http://localhost:8000/.well-known/mercure
MERCURE_JWT_SECRET="!ChangeMe!"
```

When I test it by opening symfony app in example http://localhost:8000 and adding this script in console:

```
const eventSource = new EventSource('http://localhost:8000/.well-known/mercure?topic=' + encodeURIComponent('http://example.com/books/1'));
eventSource.onmessage = event => {
    // Will be called every time an update is published by the server
    console.log(JSON.parse(event.data));
}
```

It is working and I can publish some changes in other tab.
BUT when I do the same but in my vue app which is located on http://localhost:8080 address it shows me in console error:

```
Access to resource at 'http://localhost:8000/.well-known/mercure?topic=http://example.com/books/1' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Also I got 2 more questions:

1. Why when I paste jwt token in env I got 401 errors but with this one above not?
2. Why I cant use symfony serve with https? I got errors with "TransportException: fopen(): Unable to locate certificate CN"

Answer (score 0):

It's because of CORS, because the domain where VueJS is running is different from the one where Mercure is installed.
I use Mercure with Docker compose, but if you start it from the CLI, try adding `--cors-allowed-origins='http://localhost:8000 http://localhost:8080'`

Other Question 1 : I think, you should use the same secret in .env, and in mercure config

- in `.env` : `MERCURE_JWT_SECRET="Secret123"`
- when you start mercure : `--jwt-key='Secret123'`

Comment: Nice try but unfortunately symfony binary don't recognize this parameters. 
I already fixed error with https. If someone in future wants to know why is that. Mecure dont support self signed certificates and you have to add verify_peer: false in config/dev/framework.yaml under http_client.default_configuration